# How to prevent scrolling run-on

Tags: linux

When I'm scrolling up or down in many different apps using the up/down arrow keys, if I hold the key down, then release it, I very often see the app continue to scroll, often for quite some time.  It seems that the keyboard buffer gets stuffed with key presses when the key is held down, and they all need to be processed before scrolling stops.  Can this be prevented? IOW, when I remove my finger from the key I'd like scrolling to stop.  I'm not sure at what level this problem is generated, that is to say is this Xfce's fault, or Debian's fault or Linux's fault.  However, some apps never have the problem so I don't know who to blame.

Comment: It happens when the time needed to process the scrolling of one line exceeds the key autorepeat interval. Each application would need to be modified to discard any pending input after reading one keystroke, which is not feasible and would lead to others complaining.  You could modify the autorepeat speed so that it matches the processing capability of your apps. See the `xset r` command.

Comment: Yeah, I know why it happens but is there a system wide cure?  I'm imagining something maybe at the kernel level that captures the release of the arrow key and then kills the keyboard buffer when that happens.  I actually implemented that in DOS years ago.

Answer (score 0):

With Unix-like systems (in contrast to DOS), this would be done at the application level rather than the system.  The system provides a large input buffer which you would have trouble filling up.

At the application level, most programs simply are not smart enough to recognize that they are falling behind and that the input buffer is getting filled.  They cannot *see* the input buffer.  They *can see* how much time it takes to update the screen, and measure the fraction of the time which they are doing updates.

curses applications can do some optimization by recognizing that an input character is available before completing an update.  The [typeahead](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/curs_inopts.3x.html#h3-typeahead) function controls whether the curses library will abandon an update (to work on the next update).  Other Linux terminal applications (if they are smart) can discard their input buffer using [fflush(stdin)](https://linux.die.net/man/3/fflush) — which is not portable.

Some X applications also do this type of optimization (dropping input data or output updates in response to performance problems).

But there is no *system-wide* approach to this.  Unlike DOS, Linux (and Unix) operating systems support multiple concurrent processes, and the system tries to provide resources for these.

Further reading:

- [fpurge, __fpurge - purge a stream](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/fpurge.3.html), notes that

  > Usually it is a mistake to want to discard input buffers.
- [fflush - flush a stream](https://linux.die.net/man/3/fflush) , says

  > The standards do not specify the behavior for input streams. Most other implementations behave the same as Linux.